# Changing "Advanced sharing settings" in Windows Control Panel

Tags: networking, windows-10, batch-file, c#

In my Windows 10 Control Panel I have the following settings in the "Advanced sharing settings" section of the "Network and Sharing Center":

- Media streaming - Turned on media streaming
- Password protected sharing - Turned off password protected sharing

However, after each "big" Windows 10 update (e.g. the April 2018 Update) these settings are reset.

I would like to set them via C# or a Windows batch file. Is this possible?

It is possible to programmatically open the screen in question ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38384719/2116761)), but I cannot find a way to change the settings.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: “Turned off password protected sharing” - Your screenshot says otherwise.  You are also not logged in as an Administrator.  “Save Changes” is grayed our because you have not made any changes

Comment: @Ramhound: You are right, but the screenshot is meant to show which settings I would like to set programmatically.